# Approach to speed up the processing of large files

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I have spring boot application that exposes a REST API Which accepts multipart-form data as input. The file is of CSV format. I need to parse the CSV file and fetch the unique columns from that file.

I need to speed up the processing. I was exploring the following ways to do that

1. File Channel (map function) using multiple threads in java
2. ArrayBlockingQ in java
3. Eventstream in node js

But I could not finalize with an approach. Can some one guide me the better way to handle it ? Is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: None of the above. You can read millions of lines per second with `BufferedReader.readLine()`. That's all you need.

Comment: But much of your question doesn't make sense. You don't have a file. You have an incoming data stream from a network connection. All you have to do is read it and process it. Your first suggestion involves copying it to a file and then processing that file, which only adds latency, and your second suggestion involves copying the data and presumably processing in a separate thread, which wastes both time and space.

Comment: The data is saved as a file in disk which is done by spring multipart file. 
I need to read that file. File.getbytes() will throw memory error. I need to read in chunks and process it

Comment: Well that's what I told you to do, and how to do it, and I certainly didn't say anything about `File.getBytes()`. Nobody did. Cannot imagine why you even mentioned it. It doesn't even exist.

Comment: It does exists!!  Refer org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile. And you have not given any option on how to read the file efficiently. Just the comment "You have an incoming data stream from a network connection. All you have to do is read it and process it."  But again, the file is streamed in a temp file by tomcat or any web server as matter of fact.